# SELECT ordenar pela quantidade de um outro SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, order-by

Tenho duas tabelas em MYSQL:

conta:

```
id   apelido_usuario
1    caio
2    manoel
3    josé
```

produto

```
idconta status
1       3
1       3
1       1
2       3
3       2
```

Fiz um SELECT assim:

```
SELECT * FROM conta 
WHERE apelido_usuario <> ''
AND conta.id IN (SELECT produto.idconta FROM produto WHERE produto.status = '3');
```

Funciocou como queria, ele só lista os usuarios que tem produto cadastrado e que o status desse produto é igual a 3.

Agora eu preciso de uma ORDER BY, que seja ordenado pelo usuario que tem mais produtos com o status = '3' na frente, como fazer?

Tentei algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM conta 
WHERE apelido_usuario <> ''
AND conta.id IN (SELECT produto.idconta FROM produto WHERE produto.status = '3')
ORDER BY SUM(conta.id IN (SELECT produto.idconta FROM produto WHERE produto.status = '3')) DESC;
```

Mas percebi que não é o certo...

Comment: Só pra constar, minha consulta é bem mais complexa que isso, ela tem alguns LEFT JOIN, mas que eu omiti pois não acho que venha ao caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa um left join para relacionar as 2 tabelas e fazer um `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM conta  C 
LEFT JOIN produto P ON P.idconta = C.id and  p.status = '3'
WHERE apelido_usuario <> ''
AND conta.id IN (SELECT produto.idconta FROM produto WHERE produto.status = '3')
ORDER BY P.idconta
```

Espero Ajudar.

Comment: Mas e o STATUS = 3?

Comment: Ajustei a resposta para validar o Status.

Comment: É possivel esse LEFT JOIN atrapalhar um outro que já exista na minha consulta?

Comment: Não. Pois esta usando  `LEFT JOIN`. Pode usar traqnuilo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu mudaria um pouco a forma de efetuar a consulta:

```
SELECT conta.id,
           conta.apelido_usuario, 
           count(produto.*) QtdProdutos

    FROM conta
    INNER JOIN produto
    ON produto.idconta = conta.id


    WHERE conta.apelido_usuario <> ''
    AND produto.status = '3'

    GROUP BY  conta.id,
              conta.apelido_usuario 

    ORDER BY QtdProdutos
```